# Salesmanship: How to differentiate two fulfilment statuses when both should seem attractive

Tags: icons, color-scheme, sales-techniques

My client is asking me to design text labels, iconography and colouring for two «fulfilment statuses» (apologies if that's the wrong term). Both should seem attractive to a potential customer. The paraphrased choices are:

- Your request can be granted immediately. Click here!
- We suspect your request cannot be granted immediately, and it will probably cost more than if it could. However, we would very much like you to consider it anyway, and we would love to extend you an offer. Click here!

Don't take this text literally; rather, how to phrase these labels are part of this question.

My client suggests that the first choice should be coloured green (for «ready») and the other blue (for «positive»). I'm struggling a bit to believe that's the best solution. I initially suggested a traffic light approach (green-orange/yellow-red), but the client finds that too off-putting, and I tend to agree.

Suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on context? Are these 2 options mutually exclusive, ie a user can not choose between the 2 options for the same item? Shown in list with some items available immediately, some not? With very little space? In that case, taking clues from how big e-commerce sites show stock availability could be a source of ideas.

Answer (score 4):

Without more information about the product or service, it's difficult to make specific recommendations, but here is some general advice.

There are many ways to show potential customers the difference between products, but the best thing you can do is give the customer clear and concise information upfront so they can make an informed decision.

Not matter what layout is used, the design should tell the user:

- The action required to obtain the item (Buy online now vs. contact you)
- If all of the items are not available immediately, an
  approximate timeframe (Helps the customer decide if the custom item can arrive in time)
- Why should they get the upgraded item

---

This is a quick example that shows the above list in action.

[image: image showing example of two different products with two separate fulfillment timeframes]

Another example is Microsoft's Windows purchase page (they do not need the timeframe because the download is available immediately after purchase)
[image: Screenshot of the Microsoft Windows 10 purchase page showing the comparison of windows editions]

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest iconography and color for the two choices you have.

1) Green Thumbs up icon for choice 1 which says - "Your request can be granted immediately". Thumbs up represents all ok to go ahead.

2) Blue Handshake icon for choice 2 where you would like to deal with user provided some other options. Handshake represents feasibility to enter an agreement where some of the options might be fine tuned later. This is different than rejecting or moving away from the deal.